# subset the dataframe into a new one using copy

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe `df`

```
    a    b    c
0   5    6    9
1   6    7   10
2   7    8   11
3   8    9   12
```

So if I want to select only `col a and b` and store it in another df I would use something like this

```
df1 = df[['a','b']]
```

But I have seen places where people write it this way

```
df1 = df[['a','b']].copy()
```

Can anyone let me know what is `.copy()` because the earlier code works just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example, if you want to rename a dataframe (example using `replace`):

```
df2=df
df2=df2.replace('blah','foo')
```

Here:

```
df==df2
```

Will be:

```
True
```

You want it to only do to, `df2`:

```
df2=df.copy()
df2=df2.replace('blah','foo')
```

Then now:

```
df==df2
```

Returns:

```
False
```